# understanding MRO, constructors, and methods in multiple inheritance of python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance, method-resolution-order

following is the two set of codes: one having constructor *`__init__()`*, and another having *`display()`* method.

code one:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "a"
        print(self.a)
        super().__init__()

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = "b"
        print(self.b)
        super().__init__()

class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = "c"
        print(self.c)
        super().__init__()

o = C()
print(C.mro())
```

if we compile and run this above set of codes, output will be:

```
c
a
b
[<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class 'object'>]
```

now, Second block of code is below,

```
class A(object):
    def display(self):
        self.a = "a"
        print(self.a)
        super().display()

class B(object):
    def display(self):
        self.b = "b"
        print(self.b)
        super().display()

class C(A,B):
    def display(self):
        self.c = "c"
        print(self.c)
        super().display()

o = C()
o.display()
print(C.mro())
```

if in above second block of code we replace `__init__()` with `display()` method then,
BECAUSE OF `super().display()` in `class B`, **error** will be shown
also if we remove `super().display()` in `class B` their will be no error

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'display'
```

which I understand, because `OBJECT class` does not have `display()` method in it.
**but** in the **first block** of code, the code **runs without error**.

Does that means `OBJECT CLASS` of python have `__init__()` in it?

**if not**, please explain me **why their is no error in first block of code but their is error in second block of code**?

Comment: Yes, `object.__init__` exists. It just doesn't *do* anything, but `object` is the "owner" of the method for purposes of allowing *all* classes to use `super` correctly. (Conversely, if two different classes each introduce a `display` method, neither should use `super`, but anyone trying to inherit from both needs to designate one or the other as the "primary" owner of `display`, and adapt the other to use `super` appropriately.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this code down:

---

### First snippet:

```py
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "a"
        print(self.a)
        super().__init__()


class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = "b"
        print(self.b)
        super().__init__()
```

This is a regular class in Python, no need to elaborate - it inherits from `object` - (which in [Python3 is redundant](https://codereview.doctor/features/python/best-practice/avoid-inheriting-from-object)) it calls a the `super().__init__()` which translates to `object().__init__()` - every class in Python inherits from `object` - we can see it by calling the method resolution order and noticing `<class 'object'>` in the list (last element/ only element). Same story for class `B`.

```py
class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = "c"
        print(self.c)
        super().__init__()
```

Here we have complicated things up - we have inherited from two classes: `A` and `B`. Also calling `super().__init__()` - which calls `A.__init__()` and `B.__init__()` - thus printing in the order you've seen: `c, a, b`.

---

### Second snippet:

This where things break.

```py
class A(object):
    def display(self):
        self.a = "a"
        print(self.a)
        super().display()
```

This is again, a regular class in Python with the redundant inheritance from the object class - but now we are calling `super().display()` - which translates to `object().display()` - and that method does not exist:

```py
>>> object().__init__()

None


>> object.display()

AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute 'display'
```

---

### TL;DR:

Yes, the `object` class does have `__init__()`, here it is:

```py
def __init__(self): # known special case of object.__init__
    """ Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature. """
    pass
```

no, it does not have `.display()`.